# Python: How can I compare integer data in numpy array to integer data in another numpy array and read the results into a .txt file?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, compare

I have animal locations (X,Y,Z) data and I have tree data (X, Y, Z). I need to pull all of the XYZ tree inputs that occur around animal locations- so I need to compare a numpy array containing xyz animal locations to a numpy array containing x y z point locations of trees in the same area. I want to pull all of the xyz trees in a 4 unit radius of the points and have written a function to do it. But it doesn't actually only pull the trees around the animal locations. it just prints all of the possible trees. How can I pull only the trees around the animal points and then put them into a .txt file that I can use in another program? I am new to programming and any help I can get is greatly appreciated.

the following is my code with #descriptions:

```
#using array instead of dataframe 
import numpy as np
from laspy.file import File

#load and consolidate Veg Point Coordinates into  one array
VegList = sorted(glob.glob('/Users/sophiathompson/Desktop/copys/Clips/*.las'))
VegListCoords = []
for f in VegList:
    print(f)
    Veg= File(filename = f, mode = "r")  # Open the file # Eventually, this     will need to be the actual .laz files
    VegListCoords.append(np.vstack((Veg.x, Veg.y, Veg.z)).transpose())
    print (VegListCoords)
    XYZVegComplete = np.concatenate((VegListCoords), axis = 0)

#Load animal point locations (x, y, z .csv file) from clip 240967 into array
Animal240967 =   np.loadtxt(fname='/Users/ST/Desktop/copys/CatTXTfiles/240967_CatsFt.csv', delimiter =',') 

#Use to find all vegetation heights in a 4 unit diameter of each animal    point (animalx, animaly). #'d out lines of code are my attempts to make something work 
def near_Animal(animalx, animaly):
    for x, y, z in XYZVegComplete:
        r=2 #xy coordinates in ft
        PointsNearAnml = []
        if (x-animalx)**2 + (y-animaly)**2 >= r**2:
            PracticeTxt=open("/Users/ST/Desktop/practicefilecreate.txt", "w") 
            print (x, y, z)
            #print (x, y, z) >> PracticeTxt, x, y, z
            #PracticeTxt.write('%d %d %d \n' % Points)
            #PracticeTxt.write('%d %d %d \n' % x y z)
            #Points= (x, y, z)
            #with open("/Users/sophiathompson/Desktop/practicefilecreate.txt", "w") as PracticeTxt:
            #print >> PracticeTxt, Points
            #PracticeTxt.close
#Use to call near_Animal: gather Veg Points based on proximity to animal        points (using arrays)- 
for animalx, animaly in Animal240967:
    near_Animal(animalx, animaly)
```

Comment: It's not easy to work with the code you've provided.  Consider creating a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with representative example data and expected output.  You'll be more likely to get a better answer, faster, that way.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want two different functions depending on whether you're measuring within a set or between sets.  Here's one function that does both, and some explanation of what it's doing:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, cdist
def near_fn(*args, dist = 2., outfile = "practicefilecreate.txt"):  
    if len(args) == 1:  #within a set, i.e. `Animal240967`
        coords = args[0]
        i, j = np.triu_indices(coords.size, 1)
        mask = pdist(coords, 'euclidean') < dist
        k = np.unique(np.r_[i[mask], j[mask]])
        np.savetxt(coords[k], outfile, delimiter = ',') #or whatever you want
    elif len(args) == 2: # between sets i.e. `XYZVegComplete` and `Animal240967`
        coords_ind, coords_dep = args
        k = np.any(cdist(coords_ind, coords_dep, 'euclidean') < dist, axis = 1)
        np.savetxt(coords_ind[k], outfile, delimiter = ',') #or whatever you want
    else:
        assert False, "Too many inputs"
```

What this does:

1. [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) finds the distance between elements of a set, but only finds the upper right triangle of values (since the distance between `a->b` is the same as `b->a`, and the distance `a->` is always `0`).  This is a 1-d array, which corresponds to the locations given by [`triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html).  Find the distances less than your threshold (`pdist < dist`), map that to the indices (`k = i[...]`) and write the coordinates corresponding to those indices to disk ([`np.savetxt(coords[k] . . . )`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html))
2. [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) finds the distance between two sets, as a 2-d matrix.  Find the elements less than your threshold (`cdist(ind, dep, . . . ) < dist`), find any column with a `True` in it ([`k = np.any( . . . , axis = 1)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html)) and once again, write all the coords to disk (`np.savetxt(ind[k] . . .)`)

If you have a lot of values, you may want to use a [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree) instead

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
def kd_near_fn(*args, dist = 2., outfile = "practicefilecreate.txt"):
    trees = [KDTree(arg) for arg in args]
    if len(trees) == 1:
        i, j = trees[0].query_pairs(dist)
        k = np.unique(np.r_[i, j])
    elif len(trees) == 2:
        queries = trees[0].query_ball_tree(trees[1], dist)
        k = np.array([len(query) > 0 for query in queries])
    else:
        assert False, "too many inputs"
    np.savetxt(args[0][k], outfile, delimiter = ',')
```

Comment: Daniel F thank you very much for this response. I greatly appreciate the breakdown and descriptions of what each step does that you included. it was amazingly educational for me as a new person to computer programming

Comment: Feel free to upvote and check the answer as most helpful then :)

Comment: I have been trying to use the KDTree but have not been able to get it to work. I am unsure where I put in my animal points. do i treat them as an argument in the KDTree args? for instance. in defining def_kd_near_fn(*args..... would i define animalx, animaly here?) and then reference them in trees= [KDTree(arg-animalx, animaly] and then the i,j pairs be related to the X,Y pairs for the vegetation file I am trying to pull from based on the AnimalXY pairs?

Comment: You put in one or two arrays of points, depending on if you want to find distances within one array or distances between two arrays.  `*args` can be any number of arguments, in this case I've limited it to only 1 or 2.